# Java KeyListener not responding at all

Tags: java

I am trying to make the game pong but i am having trouble with the KeyListener not working. What is wrong with the KeyListener? It is just not working and everything i look up doesn't work for me. It seems to work for other people.

Am i using it in the wrong place?

I hope anyone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Paneel extends JPanel
{
    private int height, width;
    private boolean moveLeft, moveRight, moveUp, moveDown, playerMoveLeft, playerMoveRight, computerMoveLeft, computerMoveRight;
    private Timer timer;
    private Ball ball;
    private Paddle player, computer;

    public Paneel()  
    {
        ball = new Ball(994, 772);
        player = new Paddle(1, 994, 722);
        computer = new Paddle(2, 944, 722);
        TimerHandler timerHandler = new TimerHandler();
        timer = new Timer(20, timerHandler);
        timer.start();
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) playerMoveLeft = true;
                else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) playerMoveRight = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) playerMoveLeft = false;
                else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) playerMoveRight = false;
             }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics pen)
    {
        super.paintComponent(pen);
        ball.drawBall(pen);
        player.drawPaddle(pen);
        computer.drawPaddle(pen);
    }

    public void movePlayer() 
    {
         if (playerMoveRight == true) player.moveDown();
         else if (playerMoveLeft == true) player.moveUp();
    }

    public void moveComputer() 
    {

    }

    public void resetBall()
    {

    }

    public void resetPlayer()
    {

    }

    public void resetComputer()
    {

    }

    class TimerHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            movePlayer();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `println` statements or run this in a debugger to see what blocks of code are actually being called.

Comment: In debugging it does not even enter the method of keypressed. Nor does i print a line

Comment: Not just the key listener. All over your code. Find out what *is* being called. Side note: I don't think your code is thread safe, even though you're multithreading.

Comment: Threads i know little about. For the rest everything is working fine

Comment: You need knowledge of threads to do GUI work. Especially since you're explicitly starting a separate thread (the `Timer` object).

Comment: I will look into it thanks

Answer (score -1):

set focus on your panel  by `requestFocus();` i hop that will solve the problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Too bad it does not work.

Comment: the  KeyListener work only if the ojebct who have it are focused so you can  use another solution ( not good solution but always work hhh)  ..
the other  solution is to add your key listenner  to  all panel object for example if you have a panel with two buttons(btn 1, btn2) add your KeyListener to both of them btn1 and btn2

Comment: I have no object on my panel but drawn objects